# Number of lines in all files in a directory

Tags: windows, cobol

I have a folder with many source code files.

I would like to find the total number of lines of source code in all files in the directory.

Is there any simple way to do this?

These are cobol files, I do not have a dev tool that will open them, so I cannot just run code metrics.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SLOCCOUNT](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) a well-known and free source line of code counting.

It supports COBOL and use COCOMO model to estimate effort and schedule.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using *nix, Mac OS X or even cygwin under Windows:

```
$ wc -l *
```

If you want to include subdirectories then you can do it like this:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

If you just want the grand total (i.e. skip all the individual line counts for each file) then pipe to `tail`, e.g.

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

A really quick-n-dirty way to get a close, but not exact, count would be:

```
tar -c /path/to/source/code | wc -l
```

This isn't perfectly exact, because tar adds some junk at the beginning, and between each file.  If you have any non-ascii files in your source path, that will throw things off, too.

Comment: first off, it doesn't work in windows, which is what the asker asked for

Comment: @Markasoftware: That's not what the user had asked for at the time I provided the answer. But even so, this answer can be valid in Windows, same as Paul R's answer.

Comment: It has a tag "windows" but not a comment "linux" or "unix" or "mac"

Comment: @Markasoftware: yes, and as I just explained, that tag was added after my answer was provided.

Comment: Ok then. I just saw this answer now